# Can I simulate a quantum walk in fourier space?

Tags: simulation, quantum-fourier-transform, quantum-walks

I would like to simulate a simple quantum walk in Fourier space in Python. I am hoping just to run a 1D quantum walk with a simple Hadamard coin in Fourier space. Is this possible? Do I just need to input the momentum value?